# Why there is an extra data being store in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to program a code in C++ for my assignment.

What happen is one of the part where I have to accept some data from my main and in my function I have to get first part of the array that sent by main and put in my array in the function.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(main) && exit == 0; i++){
        if (main[i] != ';' || main[i] != '\0'){

        keyword[i] = data[i];
        if(main[i] == ';' || main[i] == '\0')
        exit = 1;

        }
```

This is the code in the array named `main = "Hello World;Yes;No;Okay;Good Bye",`

So what happen is I want to store that `Hello World` in my array called `keyword` and the problem is once I printf the keyword string I see extra data after the word `Hello World`

Here is what I have on the printf

`Your keyword-----> 'Hello World;? '
Actual keyword---> 'Hello World'`

Is there any problem with my logic use above??

Thanks

Comment: I would have to see the rest of the code to be sure, but my guess is that `keyword` is a `char*` (rather than, for example, a `std::string`), in which case you need to add one `'\0'` at the end of `keyword` when the for-loop has ended.

Comment: I didn't really understand your question, but you can use the break keyword to exit from the for loop if you encounter the character ';' so that keyword contains 'hello world'

Comment: @Pramod break; is not permit in my assignment that's why I'm using exit variable to break the loop

Comment: @jogojapan I will try your solution by adding `'\0'` to the end of `keyword`

Comment: @Pramod Be sure that you have allocated enough space for `keyword`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i <= strlen(main)` needs to `i < strlen(main)` and there is no need for the extra termination character check in the `if`. Also make sure that `keyword` is null terminated (`\0`) after copying the necessary data.

Just to get you idea, assuming the destination is big enough to hold the data being copied.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(main) ; i++)
    if (main[i] != ';'){
        keyword[i] = data[i];  // Copy the characters until `;` isn't found
    } else {
        keyword[i] = '\0' ;   // If `;` found, null terminate the copied destination.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Your keyword-----> 'Hello World;?'
Actual keyword---> 'Hello World'`

Comment: This is the best solution I guess it makes the logic much simple.

I was trying to think of this but really was thinking way off and really didn't think of something simple....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The extra data you see is probably the null termination character.
Note that you are using

```
i <= strlen(main)
```

So this actually prints all the characters plus the null termination. You should change it to

```
i < strlen(main)
```

Generally in order to better understand what you do, a bit more code would really be helpfull.

But as begemoth said it appears that for what you want to do your if() test should be:

```
 if(main[i] != ';' && main[i] != '\0')
```

Comment: Please refer to the comment on @Begemoth that I have to use `||` because some of the data might not even contain the `';'` at all :)

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
if (main[i] != ';' || main[i] != '\0')
```

is always true, you want to test if the character is neither ';' nor '\0', so need to connect the test with the `&&` operator (`and`) not `||`  (`or`).

Some notes:

1. the `strlen` function has O(N) complexity it is better to call it once before the loop to determine the length of the string or replace the test with `*main[i]`.
2. The `exit` variable is redundant, use `break`.

Comment: Well I'm stating in the condition either with `';'` or the `'\0'` because some of the data doesn't have the '`;'` at all that is why I have to use `||` in this case

Comment: @Ali, I understand what you want but look closer, suppose that `main[i] == ';'` then `main[i] != ';'` equals 0, `main[i] != '\0'` equals 1 and `0 || 1` equals 1.  The same reason applies if `main[i] == '\0'`. Your condition is always true.

Comment: Even so begemoth is correct. In natural language you would say OR but try it with boolean logic. Run the if check a bit in your head and you will understand.  

Btw Ali, this is one of the most frequent bug causes in many people's codes. Misunderstanding this boolean condition and placing || instead of &&

Comment: @Begemoth, well the problem is that the data isn't always going to be the same that's why I can't use the `&&` operator in that condition else I will not pass some of the data that might only come with no semicolon at all and right away it will be false.

Comment: Why will it be false? main[i] != ';' would always be true. True && X is equal to X. So True && main[i] != '\0' would just depend on the existence or not of the null termination in the cases you refer to